# Returning a string from a http GET using asp.net web forms project

Tags: asp.net, webforms, http-get

I am trying to dynamically generate JavaScript with just a URL get request.
I have accomplished this with asp.net MVC by just returning a string from the action and writing the script tag like this.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script/get/123'></script>
```

The problem is I need to accomplish the same type of dynamically generated script from a asp.net web forms project.

How would I return dynamiccally generated string with a GET request to a page (or web service) in a asp.net Web Forms project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a [generic handler](http://lanitdev.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/ashx-generic-handler-is-underutilized/):

```
public class CustomJsHandler : System.Web.IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        context.Response.Write("alert('Hello world');");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and then specify the address of this handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/customjshandler.ashx"></script>
```